# Flutter App - Unnecessary line between containers

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a setup where I have used columns, containers and expanded widgets. There's a line between two containers. I am not sure why and which widget is generating that line. I tried providing decoration for container with 0 border to see if there was default border definition but that wasn't the case.

```
class GalleryImage extends StatelessWidget {

  final String tag;
  final ImageProvider image;

  GalleryImage(this.tag, this.image);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  border: Border.all(color:Colors.white, width:0.0, style:BorderStyle.none),
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
                child: Hero(
                  tag: tag,
                  child: Image(
                    image: image,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  border: Border.all(color:Colors.white, width:0.0, style:BorderStyle.none),
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
                width: double.infinity,
                padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10.0, 15.0, 15.0, 15.0),                 
                child:Text(
                  "Beautiful Nepal",
                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline,
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10.0, 5.0, 5.0, 0.0),                 
                  child:Text(
                    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla malesuada varius viverra. Proin malesuada id nisl a ultricies.",
                    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.body1,
                  ),
                )
              ),
            ],
          )
        ),
        Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          appBar: AppBar(
            backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
            elevation: 0.0,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );

  }

}
```

[image: Here is a screen shot]

[Here is the project repo](https://github.com/sujanbasnet/flutter-app)

Comment: set the background color of your scaffold to white.

Comment: @nick.tdr I set it to `white30` and the problem persists. When set to `white` it overlaps my container widget.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used an image but a yellow container to test your code.

I don't have a separator, here is how it looks:

[image]

What I would recommend is to try and use the **Flutter inspector** and **Select widget mode**:

[image]
And then try to tap on that widget:

[image]

It should be able to highlight the widget that is causing this behaviour and help you to further investigate.

Comment: Thank you, It helped to understand the widgets, still have to find the issue though.

Answer (score 0):

[image]Please change

```
style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline
```

to

```
style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.title
```

or  something like

```
style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 40.0, fontFamily: 'Open Sans',)
```

Comment: The line does not go away with both approaches. Here's my theme.

`ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.green,
        textTheme: TextTheme(
          body1: TextStyle(
            fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
            color: Colors.black54,
            fontSize: 15.0,
          ),
          title: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 20.0,
            fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
            color: Colors.black87,
          )
        )
      ),`

Comment: It's work with default example, I just put your code in it. Could you post other part of your code MyApp and MyHomePage etc.

Comment: For me I have 3 images right now, on one of the images it does not show the line but on the other 2 images there's line.

Comment: I have added the project repo in the question.